# Createjs DomElement Create a Form

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, createjs

I am creating an app in Cordova and I'm using Createjs for all of my graphics.  If I want to create a form so users can input their names - would I just use a textarea field (in a DIV) and just call it in a DomElement, or is there a better way to create a form in CreateJS?
Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOMElement is ideally suited to this.